# How can i plot a rolling correlation coefficient within my plot?

Tags: python-3.x, plot, correlation

This is my code. Via google i just found one hint but it wasnt really working, maybe because of the rolling(50) correlation between the two asset classes. I would like to have the Correlation Coeffiecient in kind of a legend in the upper rigth corner.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from datetime import datetime as dt, timedelta as td
from pandas_datareader import data as  pdr
import numpy as np


#'--------------------------------------
#ZUSATZ: automatic request of online data
#--------------------------------------

startyear =2020
startmonth =1
startday = 1

datestring = dt.strftime(dt.now(), "%d/%m/%Y")

start = dt(startyear,startmonth,startday) #Set starting time for datesample
now = dt.now()

asset1 = input("Enter the stock symbol (enter 'quit' to stop):").upper()
asset2 = input("Enter the stock symbol (enter 'quit' to stop):").upper()


a1 = pdr.get_data_yahoo(asset1,start,now).reset_index()
a2 =pdr.get_data_yahoo(asset2,start,now).reset_index()

a1= pd.DataFrame(a1[["Date","Adj Close"]])
a1.columns =["Date " + asset1, "Adj Close " + asset1]

a2= pd.DataFrame(a2[["Date", "Adj Close"]])
a2.columns =["Date " + asset2, "Adj Close " + asset2]

asset = pd.concat([a1,a2], axis=1)

points_to_plot = 300
fig = plt.figure()
fig.suptitle("Correlation " + datestring)
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
ax1.set_ylabel('Correaltion', fontsize = 12)
ax1.set_xlabel('Day', fontsize = 12)
label1 = ax1.set_xticklabels(ax1.get_xticklabels(), rotation = 90,fontsize=5,alpha=0.5)
ax1.set_title(f"{asset1} & {asset2}, last {points_to_plot} days", fontsize=14)

correlation_line = asset["Adj Close " +asset1].rolling(50).corr(asset["Adj Close " + asset2])[-300:].plot()
plt.legend((correlation_line, 'line-regression r={}'), 'best')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

in case anyone is interested. I solved it like this.

Of course if there is anyone who can tell me "dude you needed too much code for that", im open to learn, thanks. Im also interested if it is possible to mark the correlation of 0.79 within the Heat Map, on the line Chart.

So if anyone has an idea?

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from datetime import datetime as dt, timedelta as td
from pandas_datareader import data as  pdr
import numpy as np
import scipy as sc


#'--------------------------------------
#ZUSATZ: automatic request of online data
#--------------------------------------


startyear =2020
startmonth =1
startday = 1

datestring = dt.strftime(dt.now(), "%d/%m/%Y")

start = dt(startyear,startmonth,startday) #Set starting time for datesample
now = dt.now()

asset1 = input("Enter the stock symbol (enter 'quit' to stop):").upper()
asset2 = input("Enter the stock symbol (enter 'quit' to stop):").upper()

points_to_plot = 300

fig = plt.figure()
fig.suptitle("Correlation " + datestring)
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,2,1)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(1,2,2)
ax2.set_ylabel("Correaltion",fontsize = 12)
ax2.set_xlabel("Days", fontsize = 12)
label1 = ax1.set_xticklabels(ax1.get_xticklabels(), rotation = 90,fontsize=5,alpha=0.5)
ax2.set_title(f"{asset1} & {asset2}, last {points_to_plot} days", fontsize=14)
ax1.set_title(f"{asset1} & {asset2}, last {points_to_plot} days", fontsize=14)

a1 = pdr.get_data_yahoo(asset1,start,now).reset_index()
a2 =pdr.get_data_yahoo(asset2,start,now).reset_index()

a1= pd.DataFrame(a1[["Date","Adj Close"]])
a1.columns =["Date " + asset1, "Adj Close " + asset1]

a2= pd.DataFrame(a2[["Date", "Adj Close"]])
a2.columns =["Date " + asset2, "Adj Close " + asset2]

asset = pd.concat([a1,a2], axis=1)

correlation_line = asset["Adj Close " + asset1].rolling(50).corr(asset["Adj Close " + asset2])[-300:].plot()



df= pd.DataFrame(asset, columns=["Adj Close "+ asset1, "Adj Close " + asset2])
print(df)
corrMatrix = df.corr()
print(corrMatrix)

sns.heatmap(corrMatrix, annot=True, ax=ax1)


plt.show()
```

[image]